# Converting Float to Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a three String or Float values say 9.30, 8.00 and 0.40 as Total_hour, Paid_hour, Extra_hour

These should be actually 9 hours 30 minutes, 8 hours 0 minutes, 0 hours 40 minutes.

Question 1) How to convert 9.30 to 9 hours 30 minutes

Question 2) Later want to Subtract and get Remaining Hour = Total_hour-Paid_Hour-Extra_hour

Later the answer Remaining Hour should be in float

Comment: Is this Javascript or Python?

Comment: I want to in Javascript and in last if it not possible in javascript I can do it in Python

Comment: Now what happens if your number is `0.90`? What happens then?

Comment: I cant be like that.  Maximum it will 0.60 not more than that

Comment: Just out of curiosity I want to know why people are downvoting this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert the number in minutes and then do your subtraction. Then convert your output to hours.

```js
var Total_hour = '9.30',
    Paid_hour = '8.00',
    Extra_hour = '0.40';

var conversionInMinutes = hour => Math.floor(hour) * 60 + (hour - (Math.floor(hour))) * 100;
var conversionInHours = min => Math.floor( min/60 ) + min % 60 / 100;
var Remaining_hour = conversionInMinutes(Total_hour) - conversionInMinutes(Paid_hour) - conversionInMinutes(Extra_hour);

console.log(conversionInHours(Remaining_hour).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 6):

The following javascript snippet converts a given float to hours and minutes. Source [float to time](https://speedysense.com/convert-float-to-time-in-javascript/)

```
function convertNumToTime(number) {
    // Check sign of given number
    var sign = (number >= 0) ? 1 : -1;

    // Set positive value of number of sign negative
    number = number * sign;

    // Separate the int from the decimal part
    var hour = Math.floor(number);
    var decpart = number - hour;

    var min = 1 / 60;
    // Round to nearest minute
    decpart = min * Math.round(decpart / min);

    var minute = Math.floor(decpart * 60) + '';

    // Add padding if need
    if (minute.length < 2) {
    minute = '0' + minute; 
    }

    // Add Sign in final result
    sign = sign == 1 ? '' : '-';

    // Return concated hours and minutes
    return sign + hour + ':' + minute;
}

console.log(convertNumToTime(11.15));
```

Output

```
11:09
```

Comment: 1.999 returns "1:60"

Answer (score 5):

This should work.

You just need to convert to ms:

```js
let timefloat = 9.3;


function convertToMs(timefloat) {
  // Get the minutes portion
  let remainder = timefloat % 1;

  // Convert into ms
  let minutes = remainder * 100 * 60 * 1000;

  // Get the number of hours and convert to ms 
  let hours = (timefloat - remainder) * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  return minutes + hours;
}

// Convert back to float format
function convertToFloat(date) {
  let hours = date.getUTCHours();
  let mins = date.getUTCMinutes();
  return hours + (mins / 100);
}


// Log the result
console.log(new Date(convertToMs(9.3)).toUTCString());
console.log(new Date(convertToMs(8.0)).toUTCString());
console.log(new Date(convertToMs(9.3) - convertToMs(8.0)).toUTCString());

let diff = convertToMs(9.3) - convertToMs(8.0);
console.log(convertToFloat(new Date(diff)))
```

Comment: I will check and Inform

Comment: Later I can substract this 3 dateTimes directly ?

Comment: Once you've done the conversion to ms, you can subtract

Comment: The output is adding 4 to all the hours

Comment: @ABDevelopers That's probably because of time zone correction, try it with the change I just made so that it prints it in UTC string format

Comment: Thank you for your great answer but some other answer actually solved my issue. Output also I wanted in float. I cant accept 2 answers but I can appreciate your effort. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doTime(input)
{
    input = input.toString()
    inputs = input.split(".")
    return (inputs[0] + "Hour and" + inputs[1] + "minutes")

}

doTime("9:22")
```

function substract2

```
function subtract2(a , b){
     a = input.toString()
     arrayA = input.split(".")
     b = input.toString()
     arrayB = input.split(".")
     h = parseInt(arrayB[0]) - parseInt(arrayA[0])
     h <0 ? h+=12/*or 24*/ :h=h
     m = parseInt(arrayB[1]) - parseInt(arrayA[1])
     if(m<0){h-- ; m+=60}
     return h.toString() + ":" + m.toString()
}
```

Comment: I want this in DateTime Format so that later I can subtract as I have specified in second question

Comment: what exatcly u want in output u say need it

Comment: u need another function for subtract its your data

Comment: I have specified in question. I have 9.30 8.00 values which is string . I want to subtract this time values which is in string

Comment: its what u need?

Comment: No this is not the way I want. But thank you for your answer